# approximations of discrete distributions

Tags: statistics

if X is b(100,0.1), find the approximate value of P(12<=X<=14),using

a) The normal approximation

b) The Poisson approximation

c) The binominal

using the binominal approximation I think it would just be 100Cx*(0.1)^x * (0.9)^(100-x), and just plug in for x=12 + x=13 + x=14, but im pretty much clueless on the other two questions, any tips/solutions?:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use that if $X$ is binomially distributed with parameters $p=0.1$ and $n=100$ then $X$ can be approximated by the following distributions

1. $X \sim $ Poisson($\lambda=10$), where $10=\lambda=np=0.1\cdot100$,
2. $X \sim $ Normal($\mu=10, \sigma^2=9$), where $10=\mu=np=0.1\cdot100$ and $9=\sigma^2=np(1-p)$.

Of course, since $0.1$ is not close to $0.5$ the Poisson approximation will be much better than the normal approximation.

Comment: Are you familiar with the normal distribution, or not? If, yes then it is straightforward

Comment: I cannot explain it to you in a comment. I need three pages

Comment: It should be $\phi(1.33)-\phi(0.67)$ dude

Comment: Oh, you used also the 0.5 correction. Nice!!! then it is correct, sorry dude

Comment: You need to use the normal table. look at the back of your book

Comment: ahh ok thanks for the help!

Comment: you are welcome mate